# Does realm db supports Android 13 (API level 33)? Additionally, does Android13 allow to store db in storage?

Tags: android

I recently updated my existing Android application to target API level 33 after receiving an ultimatum from Google Play. Unfortunately, after updating to Android 13, it stops working on Android 13. Up to Android 12, it is working fine. We used realm db for storing data on the user's device, but the same technique does not work on Android 13. Could anyone confirm these two questions with some clues? (1) Does realm db support Android 13 (API level 33)? (2) Does Android 13 allow to store db in storage?

Comment: Well please first tell why it stopped working. Errors? Exceptions? Logcat? Come to the point please. Of course you can still create files in storage of device. I know nothging of Realm. Is that relevant?

Comment: By "storage" you mean app private storage (`/data/data/<packagename>`) or shared storage (`/sdcard`)?

Comment: I think it throws exception errors because of db file store. By "storage" I meant the app's private storage (/data/data/<packagename>). Thanks.

Comment: Is anyone there to help me with an effective answer to solve the issue? As per my understanding, it is all about the data-storing mechanism which may have changed in Android 13. We store data on the internal storage of the user's device.